# How do you set the value of a variable based on user input in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

In my program, the user can input a list of words or the letter n. What I want to do is when they input n, it want it to set the value of the variable where the user input is saved to a question mark (?).

Also in my program, the user inputs a different list, if they input n, I want the program to generate a word frequency table.

The problem I'm having is that when I write out the if statements for if the user input is n, I don't think that it's changing the value or creating the frequency table.

I've shifted where the code is in the program. I'm not getting the response from either if statement no matter where I put it in the code. Originally I thought the program was that I had put it near the end of the program and since it was reading it top to bottom, nothing was happening. Now, I'm not sure.

I've included the pieces of the code that would work together so I'm not pasting the entire program.

```
# Ask user for needed keywords or symbols
user_keywords = input("What keywords or special symbols would you like to search the provided file for?\n"
                  "Please separate each entry with a comma.\n If you would like to just search for question marks"
                  "please just type n.")
# Holding list, using comma as a way to separate the given words and symbols
list1 = list(user_keywords.split(','))
# Print list for user to see
print("You have entered the following keywords and/or special symbols: ", list1)

# Ask user for needed repeating words
user_repeating = input("What repeating words would you like to search the provided file for?\n"
                  "Please separate each entry with a comma. \n If you would like a frequency table for all words"
                   "two letters or more, please type n.")
# Holding list, using comma as a way to separate the given words and symbols
list2 = list(user_repeating.split(','))
# Print list for user to see
print("You have entered the following words: ", list2)

frequency = {}

# Check to see if list1 has no parameters and sets to ?
if list1 == 'n':
    list1 = '?'
    print("We will search for any question marks.")

# Check to see if list2 has no parameters and creates a frequency array
if list2 == 'n':
    document_text = open (path1, 'r')
    text_string = document_text.read().lower()
    match_pattern = re.findall(r'\b[a-z]{2-20}\b', text_string)
    print("We will look for all word frequencies.")

    for word in match_pattern:
        count = frequency.get(word,0)
        frequency[word] = count + 1

    frequency_list = frequency.keys()

    for words in frequency_list:
       print(words, frequency[words])
```

I expect list1 to be set to ? when n is entered by the user. I expect list2 to generate a word frequency table when n is entered by the user.

I'm not getting any errors. At this point is just goes straight to the end of the program and returns the final print line I have in it, so I know it isn't calling the if statements.

Comment: If `list1` and `list2` are lists, then they cannot be equal to `'n'`. A list is not a string.

Comment: @khelwood the user is providing a list of words, if they just provide n, wouldn't that be in the first position of the list? I can get the program to return the list when it is a collection of words, but I don't know if I'm setting the value correctly when it the list just contains n. If that makes sense.

Comment: You need to specify the element in the list. list1[0] == n:

Answer (score 0):

Surely the way to do this is to replace:

`list1 = list(user_keywords.split(','))`

with

`list1 = '?' if user_input == 'n' else list(user_keywords.split(','))`

no?